# Found conflicts between different versions of the > same dependent assembly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Using the latest Xamarin bits, I'm now getting the following warnings in Visual Studio for Mac:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.8.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2057,5):
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of
>   "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.  These reference
>   conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
>   detailed.
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.8.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2057,5):
>   warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning
>   (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add
>   the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the
>   application configuration file: 
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2245,3):
>   warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning
>   (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add
>   the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the
>   application configuration file:

I have all of the latest nuget packages installed, I've tried clean / rebuild, and I've uninstalled the app from my device. The app seems to build and deploy to device fine, however I'm concerned that this will cause trouble (maybe with release builds.) Is there a fix coming from Xamarin for this?

Comment: The reference to Microsoft.CSharp can usually be removed without any  disadvantages.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I removed the nuget package for Microsoft.CSharp and then cleaned and rebuilt, and it still gives the same warning: MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.